# Remove Bing OnTouch event

Tags: c#, xaml, bing-maps

I will attempt to describe my problem.

I am creating a simple map application that plots the location of my home.

I would like to be able to press a button that LOCKS the screen so the map cannot scroll.

I currently have everything working, the only problem is I cannot figure out how to remove the OnTouch event that currently Pans/Zooms the map. I am using BING API with C#/XAML.

Does anyone know how to prevent the touch events from panning or moving about the map?

Comment: Is this for WP 7, 8, 8.1, Windows Store App, or WPF?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the map center and zoom values when the lock button is pressed and then use the view change event to set the maps center and zoom to these values. This will cause the map to lock.